# TypeScript Index Signatures with Interface Types

Tags: typescript

I have an interface and a class:

```
interface Widget {
  widgetStuff(): void;
}

class Foo implements Widget {
  widgetStuff(): void {
  }
}
```

I want to track all of the `Widget`s in another class, and an index signature seems to be the easiest way:

```
class WidgetCatalog {
  private readonly mapping: { [key: string]: Widget };

  constructor() {
    this.mapping = {
      Foo // <= Error here
    }
  }
}
```

I'm getting this error: `error TS2322: Type 'typeof Foo' is not assignable to type 'Widget'.
  Property 'widgetStuff' is missing in type 'typeof Foo'.`

I'm not sure what Im missing here, since it seems to be a pretty straightforward implementation.  Do I need to specify the value type in the index signature differently?

Comment: `this.mapping.Foo` will be `Foo`, the class constructor that makes new `Widget`s.  It's not a `Widget` itself.  So either `mapping` should hold `Widget` constructors, in which case it's mis-annotated, or `this.mapping` should be initialized to `{Foo: new Foo()}` or something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@jcalz pointed me in the right direction. This version works:

```
interface Widget {
  widgetStuff(): void;
}

class Foo implements Widget {
  widgetStuff(): void {
  }
}

class WidgetCatalog {
  // Change to mapping of Widget constructors
  private readonly mapping: { [key: string]: new(...args) => Widget };

  constructor() {
    this.mapping = {
      Foo
    }
  }
}
```